# Class template argument deduction for array of function pointer works on clang, but not on gcc

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

The following code:

```
#include <array>

template <int i>
auto f(){}

int main () {
    std::array{f<5>};
}
```

compiles with clang 7.0, but fails with gcc 8.2 with the message

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:7:20: error: class template argument deduction failed:
     std::array{f<5>};
                    ^
prog.cc:7:20: error: no matching function for call to 'array(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
In file included from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/array:244:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class ... _Up> std::array(_Tp, _Up ...)-> std::array<typename std::enable_if<(is_same_v<_Tp, _Up> && ...), _Tp>::type, (1 + sizeof... (_Up))>'
     array(_Tp, _Up...)
     ^~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/array:244:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:7:20: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     std::array{f<5>};
                    ^
In file included from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/array:94:12: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> array(std::array<_Tp, _Nm>)-> std::array<_Tp, _Nm>'
     struct array
            ^~~~~
/opt/wandbox/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/array:94:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:7:20: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
     std::array{f<5>};
                ^
```

Is this code legal? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you define `f` without `auto`, [gcc accepts it](https://godbolt.org/z/J_U7ZV)

Comment: `template <int i> auto f() -> void {} ` is fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the program is well formed. I faced a similar problem myself recently. GCC seems to have issues when it needs to deduce the placehoder return type while in the process of deducing the array arguments. Specifying the return type explicitly as `void` would make GCC accept your code, for instance.

Ultimately, the workaround is to split the declarations.

```
auto *p = f<5>;
std::array{p};
```

Comment: Is there a bug report somewhere?

Comment: @YSC - No idea. I tried to look on bugzilla when I faced the issue myself, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Thanks. The workaround with avoiding the `auto` return type would be feasible in real code, fortunately. (It's not quite `void`, but simple enough.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen - I was also going to add, with regard to your original example. I too had a pack on my hands. `std::common_type` was what I ended up using eventually. And so specified the array type without CTAD.

Comment: What do you think of http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#3.sentence-4 _"If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function ([stmt.if])."_?

Comment: @YSC - We aren't deducing a function's type by taking it's address. The specialization had its argument provided explicitly (and then the address taken). But it may point at where GCC is choking, IDK.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying I'm unsure `auto f(){}`is well-formed.

Comment: @YSC - Note the "if any". It acknowledges there may be none, in which case the return type is `void`.

Comment: Changing `f` to return something, e.g. `template <int i>
auto f(){return 5;}`, also does not change anything about the issue at hand, fwiw.

Comment: That's where my english skills limit me I fear. I was reading it as "if there is a return statement, then the function return type can be deduced."